# Firebase app invite no send any SMS

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-invites

I am trying to use the Firebase appinvite to invite friends to use my app (android). Sms are not sending. I do not get any error message. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be in message content - message is not sent if it contains ellipsis symbol, for example. Could you add message content to the question?

Comment: Why is it not sent if it contains ellipsis?